# FInding the dimension of a subspace $U = \{p(x) \in V | p(3)=p(5)=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let

$$
V = \{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d|a,b,c,d \in Z_7\}
$$

Let the subspace $U$ Be a subspace of $V$:

$$
U = \{p(x) \in V | p(3)=p(5)=0\}
$$

The answers says that:

$$
Dim(U) = 2
$$

How did they conclude that the dimension of $U$ Is $2$?

Comment: Two independent linear equations decrease the dimension by two.

Comment: @Berci and if I have a condition saying $p(1)=p(2)=p(3)=...=p(6) = 0$ You would conclude it has a dimension of $6$? Which is surly impossible

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is the set of all $4$ dimensional vectors such that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
27 &  9 & 3 & 1\\
125& 25 & 5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
Since this matrix is of rank $2$, therefore, its kernel is of dimension $2$, by rank nullity theorem.

Comment: I don’t understand what you did. What is this matrix that you built? How did you get to $27,9,3,1$ For example?

Comment: @Alon, $27=3^3, 9=3^2, 3=3^1$, therefore, $\begin{pmatrix}27&9&3&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}$ is the value of a polynomial at $3$ with coefficients $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$.

Comment: We want the polynomial to be zero at $3$, hence, the vector of coefficients is orthogonal to the first row vector of the matrix I constructed.

Comment: Similarly it is orthogonal to the second row and hence is in the kernel of this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is the subspace of polynomials of $V$ that have $3$ and $5$ as roots. Then every element of $U$ is divided by $(x-3)(x-5)$. So:
$$
U=\{p(x)\in V \ | \ p(x) = (x-3)(x-5)(mx+n)\}
$$
Hence $U$ has dimension $2$ and a base of $U$ is
$$
\mathcal B_U = \{(x-3)(x-5) , x(x-3)(x-5)\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you've reduced the dimension by $2$ by placing the two restrictions: $p(3) = 0$ and $p(5) = 0$. This gives you the dimension as $4 - 2 = \boxed{2}$.

---

Formally: We find the necessary and sufficient conditions that $a, b, c, d$ must satisfy so that $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \in U$.

We get this by assuming $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and imposing the conditions $p(3) = 0$ and $p(5) = 0$.

This gives us that the set of all possible tuples $(a, b, c, d)^T$ is precisely the kernel $K$ of 
$$\begin{pmatrix}3^3 & 3^2 & 3 & 1\\5^3 & 5^2 & 5 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The above matrix clearly has rank $2$ and thus, the dimension of its kernel is $2$. (Rank-nullity theorem.)

Now, given two basis elements $(a_1, b_1, c_1, d_1)$ and $(a_2, b_2, c_2, d_2)$ of $K$, we define
$$p_i(x) = a_ix^3 + b_ix^2 + c_ix + d_i; \quad i = 1, 2.$$

Now, $\{p_1(x), p_2(x)\}$ forms a basis for $U$. Thus, the dimension is $\boxed{2}$.

---

Another way is the following, which easily generalises:
Let $p(x) \in U.$ Then, we clearly have that $x - 3$ and $x - 5$ divide $p(x)$.
As $p(x)$ is of degree at most $3$, the quotient upon division is of degree at most $1$. Consider the vector space
$$U' = \{ax + b \mid a, b \in \Bbb Z_7\}.$$

We have the following linear map $T:U' \to U$ 
$$T(q(x)) = q(x)(x - 3)(x - 5).$$

It is easy to show that $q$ is a bijection. Thus, we have that $\dim U = \dim U'$. Clearly, we have that $\dim U' = \boxed{2}.$